# Laravel: how to send text input as route parameter?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, query-string

**view**

```
<form method="GET" action="{{ route('searchproduct',['page'=>1]) }}" >
    <input id="q" name="q" type="text" />
    <button type="submit" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-primary">Go</button>
</form>
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('product/search/{page}/{q?}','ProductController@search')->name('searchproduct');
```

**Controller**

```
public function search(Request $request)
    {
        //processing

        return view('products',['products'=> $search_results]);
    }
```

after submitting the form, the url looks like this:

> example.com/appname/public/product/search/1?q=search+this

I want it always to look like this:

> example.com/appname/public/product/search/1/search+this

Comment: you can retrieve your input and redirect to route which you wanted to, or build action attribute with js

Comment: ok I just used this code but I get "The page isn’t redirecting properly" error  <<<<< return redirect()->route('searchproduct',[
   'q'=>$request->q,
   'page'=>$request->page,
   'products'=> $search_results
  ]); >>>>>

Comment: When you submit a `GET` form, it appends it's contents to the URL as a query string, like `?key=value&another=something...`. What you want to do is intercept the form submit using JavaScript, append the value of your `q` input to the URL of your form's `action` attribute, and redirect. That's a bit broad, but see if you can implement that and update this question if you run into any issues.

Answer (score 0):

In your form add ID.

### View

```
<form id="search" method="GET" action="{{ route('searchproduct',['page'=>1]) }}" >
    <input id="q" name="q" type="text" />
    <button type="submit" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-primary">Go</button>
</form>
```

### JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){    
    jQuery("form#search").on('submit',function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var q = jQuery("#q").val();
          window.location.href = jQuery(this).prop('action')+"/" + encodeURIComponent(q)        
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<form id="search" method="POST" action="{{ route('searchproduct',['page'=>1]) }}" >
<input id="q" name="q" type="text" />
<button type="submit" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-primary">Go</button>
</form>

public function search(Request $request,$page,$q='')
{
    //processing

    return view('products',['products'=> $search_results]);
}

Route::post('product/search/{page}/{q?}','ProductController@search')->name('searchproduct');
```

I guess due to `GET` you are getting `example.com/appname/public/product/search/1?q=search+this` url.